# How to add rules to vuetify draggable?

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuedraggable

I'm a beginner in vuetify and I made a project where you can add courses to a timetable via vue-draggable. How can I make it possible that I can't drag a course to a certain day because this course isn't offered on this day? And you'll get an error message if you try to add this course and it will be not possible to drag. I tried with rules. But it doesn't work.
Here a snippet:

```
<v-card class="ma-2 pa-2">
        <draggable :id="index" v-model="course" :options="{group:'course'}" @start="drag=true"
                   @end="drag=false" @add="newCourse" :rules="courseRules">
          <v-card-title class="headline">
            {{ capLetter(index) }}
          </v-card-title>
        </draggable>
```

Can anyone plz help me? Are there any other techniques?
Thank you

Comment: You should at least provide some code sample, showing your what you tried to achieve what you want. As you wrote it, this is not a question : you're actually asking people to do all the work ;)

Comment: I'm sorry it was not my intension...I'm new here and didn't want a whole solution. I just want to know if there are any other techniques than what I tried. I tried to add rules but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable the draggable functionality you have to work with the `:disabled` attribute.

Example:

```js
<draggable :disabled="!enabled">
...
</draggable>
```

`enabled` must have a truthy or a falsy value.

You can find an official example here: https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next/blob/master/example/components/simple.vue